# Layer Stroke - PS 2024?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

We are now on Photoshop 2024, and I'm curious if we can add a Stroke (layer style), with sharp corners (not rounded) and adjust the stroke opacity. My answer will be NO, but I wanted to reach out to the community to confirm if this is still the case. I hope I'm wrong. ;)  Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Hi. What's on the layer?  What kind of graphic is it?  Is it complex, or something simple?  Can you show us what you tried or what has failed? Does it have to be automated, or will you accept manual methods? There may be alternatives to try. Please edit your question and add more details. Thanks.

Comment: @BillyKerr  Most anyone seasoned at using Photoshop knows precisely what I'm asking above. With that said, I added an example to clarify a bit more.

Comment: The reason I asked for images was to see what kind of work you are actually trying to do.  I know what you are talking about, but context can change everything.  I don't think it's possible in Photoshop just using stroke effects. (You know this already).  It might be better to consider using Illustrator or a similar vector image editor. You can adjust stroke and fill opacity, and stroke corners easily in vector software [see an example](https://imgur.com/DP4KyAG). When it comes to vector functionality, unfortunately Photoshop is quite limited by comparison.

Comment: You could even create the boxes in Illustrator, and place the AI file directly into Photoshop as a Linked File to finish the rest of your edit in Photoshop

Comment: Understood.  Yes, copying/importing a vector file as a smart-object is probably another option and probably the best one. It's odd, that a function so seemingly simple hasn't been addressed for Photoshop. Perhaps there are technical reasons but I can't think of one. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: Not so much a technical reason, but there kind of is a practical reason in that Photoshop is a raster image editor which was initially designed for editing photographic images - this is really its forté, what it excels at, and Adobe has mostly stuck with that vision for their product. Also, since Adobe already makes a vector image editor, there's really no point in replicating all of Illustrator's vector functionality in Photoshop.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this doesn't *technically* answer the question, but....

Move the layer style stroke to the **inside** and increase the size of the rectangle to compensate. The result will have sharp corners.

The opacity of the (inside) stroke will *override* the opacity of any fill.

This has really *always* worked to get around the rounded layer style stroke. It's only the "outer" or "centered" layer style strokes which have rounded corners. "Inside" strokes will be restricted to the underlying shape.

[image]

There are, of course, other methods as well.